# SonarQube P2 repository has gone forever

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, p2

[Codehaus](http://www.codehaus.org/) is shutting down its services, including the Eclipse Plugin of SonarQube. Does anyone know whether there is already a replacement for the P2 repository http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/ ?

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new update URL is: http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/

This will be updated on the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: yes we can setup sonar qube using this link in eclipse